# Can I continue coding if ($a[undefined]) as false?

Tags: php

I wonder my code has security risk or etc?

This code cause Notice Error.

```
<?php
$array = array();
if ($array['hoge']) {
}
?>
```

And I set ~E_NOTICE in php.ini.

Should I use empty()?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you doing this? What exactly is your question? What you have is very bad practice, regardless of what you're trying to achieve with it.

Comment: yes, always use empty or isset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notice error is caused because you are checking if $array['hoge'] is either TRUE or FALSE, when in fact the value isn't even set. The correct way to code your previous if conditional would be:

```
<?php
$array = array();
if !empty($array['hoge'])
{
  //...code executed inside conditional...
}
?>
```

It is good practice to check if the array is both set and if it's not empty. I hope that helps! :)

Comment: Either `empty` or `isset` is redundant. Just `!empty($array['hoge'])` is fine

Comment: @empty there are situations where that isn't true. When passing values from one site to another via superglobals, some older browsers send set variables even if values were not input directly. Heard that from a harvard cs50 class on php given over youtube :). If you want a source I can search one for you, though the video was 2 hours long and would have to put a little effort in finding that specific part of the class.

Comment: Well, what you just said is not true. `isset` is **always** redundant when you already have `empty`. Not to mention that browsers have no control on how server side code is executed. And thanks, no need for source - just check it yourself or in the documentation.

Comment: I stand corrected! I wasn't wrong about the values being set in specific versions of old browsers, but rather on how `empty` works, and in the documentation it does say it returns `FALSE` if the value is empty or is not set. wp

Comment: "about the values being set in specific versions of old browsers" --- this does not sound right. At least in the way it is stated.